# Define the prototype of a function with a std::vector as input parameter in an header

Tags: c++, function, vector, header

I'm getting crazy since i'm not able to define the prototype of a function i'm actually using.
 What i'm doing is create an header file called `func1.h`where i define this prototype (that's because i need to invoke this function from some other function implemented elsewhere):

```
void FileVector(std::vector<Files> &,const char*,bool);
```

Where `Files`is a struct defined in `func1.cpp`

```
struct Files{
        HANDLE h;
        WIN32_FIND_DATA info;
        } file;
```

I have also another function that accept a `std::vector<Files> &` as input parameter but when i try to compile (using Eclipse C++) i'm getting those errors:

```
/FileVector.h:11:22: error: variable or field 'FileVector' declared void
..\/FileVector.h:11:17: error: 'vector' is not a member of 'std'
..\/FileVector.h:11:29: error: 'Files' was not declared in this scope
```

I've tryied to include several directive in the header file..for example declaring the struct in the header and including vector header do the trick but this way i got loads of "multiple definitions/first defined here" error.
What can i do?

## EDIT

Now my header looks like:

```
#ifndef FILEVECTOR_H_
#define FILEVECTOR_H_
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>

 struct Files{
        HANDLE h;
        WIN32_FIND_DATA info;
        };

 void FileVector(std::vector<Files> &,const char*,bool);

 #endif /* FILEVECTOR_H_ */
```

At this point, i need to declare another prototype in another header:

```
void ProcessInput(vector<Files>&);
```

but i can't use the same trick as above cause i'll have to re-define the Files struct. How can i solve this?

Comment: You might get better answers to this question if you posted a [complete, minimal example](http://sscce.org/). It's hard to second guess the exact structure of your code without seeing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to include `<vector>` in your header file. You also mention that the definition of `Files` is within the cpp file, you should move it to the header as well.

Also place proper header guards to avoid multiple definition errors:

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER_FILE_GUARD
#define MY_HEADER_FILE_GUARD

... your content here ...

#endif /*MY_HEADER_FILE_GUARD*/
```

**Update:**
Simply including `filevector.h` from your new header would do. However, it looks like `Files` should be defined in a header of its own and included from the two headers that make use of it.

Comment: What if i need to declare another prototype, with the same input parameter, but in another header? I've just edited the original post to be more precise.Thanks.

Comment: I was about to ask why you don't use `#pragma once` instead of the header guards, but I just found out (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once) it's non-standard!